# Why does this error pop up, what are your thoughts on my neural network/genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, compiler-errors, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

Preamble:
     This is a combination of my first and second programs in python *(besides hello world level tutorials)*. Any questions I've had have led me to this site so it seemed fitting that I post it here.  I come from a TI-Basic background; so if you have no idea why I did it this why when you should do it this why that is likely why.

My first program was a genetic learning algorithm. Its testing setup was/is to guess your input string. There is currently a problem with it, but it only slightly affects the efficiency of the program.[1]

My second is a simple feed forward neural network *(I am currently only working on the xor problem)*.  Some of the code for customizing the variables *(the number of inputs, the number of outputs, the number of hidden layers, the number of neurons in those hidden layers)* is there but is currently not my focus.

What I am trying to do now is train my network with my genetic algorithm.  All seems to be fine but I keep getting a un-explanable error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 174, in <module>
File "python", line 68, in fitness_function
File "python", line 146, in weight_dot_value_plus_bias
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Now the weird thing is, the code this is referring to is a direct transfer of code from the original neural network.

I am using repl.it as my compiler, could that be the problem?

```
import random
from random import choice
from random import randint

#Global varables


length_of_phrase = 15
generation_number = 0
max_number_of_generations = 250

population = 150

perckill = 40

percparents = 35

percrandom = 1

percmutate = 1

individual_by_gene_matrix = [0]
one = 1
zero = 0

number_of_layers = 3
number_of_neurons = [2,3,1]
nnv = [0]*number_of_layers
nnw = [0]*number_of_layers
nnb = [0]*number_of_layers


val1 = randint(0,1)
val2 = randint(0,1)

living = int(((100 - perckill)*population)//100)
dead = population - living
random_strings = int((( percrandom)*population)//100)
reproduced_strings = int(living + random_strings)
parents = int(((100 - percparents)*population)//100)
"""
print(living)
print(dead)
print(population)
print(random_strings)
print(reproduced_strings)
"""
def random_matrix_generator():  #generates a matrix With = number of genes in the target and Hight = population
    from random import randint
    individual_by_gene_matrix = [[randint(-200, 200)/100 for x in range(length_of_phrase)] for x in range(population)]
    #horozontal is traits, vertical is individual
    #each gene represents a letter
    #each individual represents a word
    return(individual_by_gene_matrix)
""" 
def convert_matrix_into_list_of_stings():
    listofstrings = [ () for var in range( population)]
    for var in range( population ):
        list = individual_by_gene_matrix[var]       #creates a list for each individual with their traits
        lista = [ (chr(n )) for n in list]      #the traits become letters
        listofstrings[var] = ''.join(lista)     #creates a list of all the individuals with letters joined
    return(listofstrings)
""" 
def fitness_function():
        for individual in range (population):
            number_of_layers,number_of_neurons ,nnv,nnw,nnb = NN_setup(val1,val2,individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][0],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][1],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][2],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][3],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][4],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][5],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][6],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][7],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][8],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][9],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][10],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][11],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][12],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][13],individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][14])
            for var in range (1,number_of_layers):
                nnv = weight_dot_value_plus_bias(var)
                nnv = sigmoid(var)





            fitness[individual] = 1-abs((val1 ^ val2)- (nnv[2][0]))
    #for n in range(population):
    #print('{} : {} : {}'.format(n, listofstrings[n], fitness[n]))
        return(fitness)

def matrix_reorder():
    temp_individual_by_gene_matrix = [[0 for var in range(length_of_phrase)] for var in range(population)]
    temp_fitness = [(0) for var in range(population)]
    for var in range(population):
        var_a = fitness.index(max(fitness))
        temp_fitness[var] = fitness.pop(var_a)
        temp_individual_by_gene_matrix[var] = individual_by_gene_matrix.pop(var_a)
    return(temp_individual_by_gene_matrix, temp_fitness)

def kill():

    for individal in range(living, population):
        individual_by_gene_matrix[individal] = [0]*length_of_phrase
    return(individual_by_gene_matrix)

def reproduce():
    for individual in range(living,reproduced_strings):
        for gene in range(length_of_phrase): 
            individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][gene] = randint(-200,200)/100


    for individual in range(reproduced_strings, population):
        mom = randint(0,parents)
        dad = randint(0,parents)
        for gene in range(length_of_phrase):
            individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][gene] = random.choice([individual_by_gene_matrix[mom][gene],individual_by_gene_matrix[dad][gene]])

    return(individual_by_gene_matrix)

def mutate():
    for individual in range(population):
        for gene in range(length_of_phrase):
            if randint(0,100)<=percmutate:
                individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][gene] = random.gauss(individual_by_gene_matrix[individual][gene],0.5)
    return(individual_by_gene_matrix)




def NN_setup(val1,val2,w100,w101,w110,w111,w120,w121,w200,w201,w202,b00,b01,b10,b11,b12,b20):

    number_of_layers = 3
    number_of_neurons = [2,3,1]
    nnv = [0]*number_of_layers
    nnw = [0]*number_of_layers
    nnb = [0]*number_of_layers

    for layer in range ( number_of_layers ):
        nnv[layer] = [0]*number_of_neurons[layer]
        nnw[layer] = [0]*number_of_neurons[layer]
        nnb[layer] = [0]*number_of_neurons[layer]
        if layer != 0:
            for neuron in range (number_of_neurons[layer]):
                nnw[layer][neuron] = [0]*number_of_neurons[layer - 1]



    nnv = [[val1,val2],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0]]
    nnw = [['inputs have no weight'],[[w100,w101],[w110,w111],[w120,w121]],[[w200,w201,w202]]]
    nnb = [[b00,b01],[b10,b11,b12],[b20]]
    return(number_of_layers,number_of_neurons,nnv,nnw,nnb)

|
|
|
v
def weight_dot_value_plus_bias(layer):
    for nueron in range (number_of_neurons[layer]):
        for weight in range (number_of_neurons[layer - 1]):

    --->    nnv[layer][nueron] += (nnv[layer-1][weight])*(nnw[layer][nueron][weight])

        nnv[layer][nueron] += nnb[layer][nueron]
    return(nnv)

def sigmoid(layer):
    for neuron in range(number_of_neurons[layer]):
        nnv[layer][neuron] = (1/(1+3**(-nnv[layer][neuron])))
    return(nnv)





individual_by_gene_matrix = random_matrix_generator()


while (generation_number <= max_number_of_generations):
    val1 = randint(0,1)
    val2 = randint(0,1)

    fitness = [(0) for var in range(population)]

    #populations_phenotypes_by_individual = convert_matrix_into_list_of_stings()




    fitness = fitness_function()

    individual_by_gene_matrix , fitness = matrix_reorder()

    individual_by_gene_matrix = kill()

    individual_by_gene_matrix = reproduce()

    individual_by_gene_matrix = mutate()

    individual_by_gene_matrix , fitness = matrix_reorder()

    #populations_phenotypes_by_individual = convert_matrix_into_list_of_stings()


    print('{} {}      {}   {}'.format(generation_number,(10000(fitness[0]))//100),val1,val2)

    generation_number += 1

print('')
print('')
print(individual_by_gene_matrix[0])
```

That was way to many indents!!!

How the hell do I just insert a block of code????!!!!!

I'll give you the source code to the individual programs once I learn how to insert a block of code

[1]  Your going to have to wait till I give you the source code to just the genetic algorithm

Any tips, suggestions, maybe how would you write the code to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you are declaring nnv, nnw and nnb as integer arrays of size 3 and later trying to access them as multi-dimensional arrays. This is giving you the error.

Comment: In line 137 - 139 they are redeclared as a list within a list (in the case of nnw list of lists of lists)

Comment: Are you sure that it will work the way you wanted it to? Can you print the arrays after redeclaration and check if they are okay

Comment: I have rebuilt this programs multiple times and have not had that error any other time